# Spring-Ldap Alternative

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Anyone knows an library for Ldap Access and Manipulation with features like spring-ldap? http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/ or that is the only alternative.
The only project I could find that come close is the Apache Directory API http://directory.apache.org/api/

First reason I'm searching for alternatives is because the project will be created in Java EE and spring-ldap is more linked with spring framework. I could make the two thinks work toggether but the second reason is simple to know alternatives.

The native aproach in java is too painful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for alternatives but the following two projects (and the development tools that they provide) are possible options:

- [OpenDJ](http://opendj.forgerock.org) - They provide an SDK for accessing any LDAPv3 server not just their own. This can be found here: http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-ldap-sdk/
- [OpenLdap](http://www.openldap.org) - Again they provide a set of libraries for connecting to any LDAPv3 server, details of which can be found here: http://www.openldap.org/jldap/

Of the two have only used OpenDJ - but was fairly happy with the experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is not much alternatives to ldap in java, I'm current using apache directory API. OpenDJ appear to be good, my first impression reading the examples is a little more verbose than apache, but the documentation is far more complete, because apache is relative new.